# Shell script / Python3 file on crontab

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, cron

I try to run the schedule.sh (shell script) in the crontab

This is the code in the script

```
#!/bin/sh -x
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/home/peteryph/bin:/home/peteryph/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin  

python3 main_schedule.py
echo "Finish"
```

In the crontab terminal (crontab -e)

```
* * * * * /home/peteryph/Desktop/working/city_google/schedule.sh > /home/peteryph/Desktop/working/city_google/echo2.txt
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/peteryph/Desktop/working/city_google /schedule.py > /home/peteryph/Desktop/working/city_google/echo.txt
```

In the cron status

```
(peteryph) CMD (/home/peteryph/Desktop/working/city_google/schedule.sh > /home/peteryph/Desktop/working/city_google/echo2.txt)
(peteryph) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/peteryph/Desktop/working/city_google /schedule.py > /home/peteryph/Desktop/working/city_google/echo.txt)
```

In the main_schedule, the code looks like this

(I did import the files. They are a lot of them, so I did not put them right here.)

```
print("Please wait.........\n")
infor = update()
infor.clear_previous_value() #update the data in the DB
start_time = time.time()
infor.select_update() #insert the data into DB
print("Running time --%s seonds--" %(time.time() - start_time) + "\n")
sys.exit()
```

I try to execute both python file and script at the same time, but I only receive the echo from the python file. But the data did not insert into the Database on both python file and script on the crontab.

However, the script works when I execute it manually.

(I do have non-English character in my file, would that effect the crontab ?)

(Or does the path of the database has to be absolute path ? )

Answer (score 0):

I found where the PROBLEMS are.

First, you have to use absolute path for your database when you call the database for sqlite3.

Second, make sure your shell script is executable :P